# LightStreamer DotNet compiled as a PCL project for Xamarin

Tags: c#, lightstreamer

I've been trying to discuss this with someone from the LightSteamer technical department but it seems the technical support e-mail links directly to the sales team.

Currently there are 4 DotNet clients for LightStreamer.

- DotNetClient_N2 (Compiled with .NET version 3.5)
- DotNetClient_WinRT (Compiled with .NET version 4.6)
- WindowsPhoneClient (Compiled with .NET version 4.6)
- Silverlight (Compiled with .NET version 4.6)

None of these are compatible with Xamarin out of the box. Unfortunately because I don't have access to the source code I can't adapt any of them and recompile them as a PCL.

If someone from LightStreamer could port one of these to .NET version 4.5 in a PCL compatible format that would be ideal. I'm not sure if I have the technical expertise to implement my own generic HTTP solution.

Comment: Just a necessary clarification on your first sentence. The Lightstreamer technical support email doesn't link directly to the sales team, it is filtered by the account management team to identify the customer that is doing the request. In case of end users of Lightstreamer's customers and users of the free edition of the product, the support team will answer promptly through the public forum: http://forums.lightstreamer.com/. This way, answers can help other users too.

Comment: Okay thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can confirm that at the moment the Lightstreamer .NET Client libraries are four, each specific for target platform:

- .NET Client Desktop
- Windows Phone
- WinRT
- Silverlight Client

However, it is expected in a short time a PCL version of Lightstreamer .NET Client library, with the intention to replace all the old ones.

Furthermore, it is also planned, though later in time, a UWP (Universal Windows Platform) library based on JavaScript.

I can also confirm that the Lightstreamer support team will contact you asap to let you know the ETA for the PCL lib.

Comment: Yea thank you, that would be great, looking at the code for the .NET client libraries it looks like they all use the old HttpRequest system. If they could be updated to use HttpClient with async and await. Then I can ModernHttpClient plugin for native Http requests on iOS and Android.  Much faster.